# C++: renaming templated class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I'm looking for some code to make it work

```
template <typename T, int a, int b> 
class first 
{   //not so important
};

main()
{
first<double,1,2> sth;
second<double> sth2;
}
```

Sth2 is the same type as sth, but has default parameters  (for example)
I do know I need some typedef. I tried

```
template <typename T>
struct help
{
typedef first<T,1,1> second;
};
```

but it works only with additional :: (help< double>::second) and i just want to change it for second< double>

Thank you for any ideas :)

Comment: If you are blessed with a C++11-conforming compiler, you can write `template <typename T> using second = first<T, 1, 1>;`

Comment: Yep, that's the problem, I'm not blessed with C++11 at all :C

Comment: Well, then you are stuck with more verbose, less aesthetically satisfying solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to define

```
template <typename T, int a=1, int b=2> class first
```

and then

```
first<double> sth2;
```

But if you really want two classes

```
template <typename T> class second : public first<T,1,1>
```

Should get you somewhere.

Comment: Derivation is a nice idea (+1), but without C++11's ctor inheritance you might need to repeat `first`'s ctors in `second`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using default parameters? Otherwise igor might be right with C++11

Comment: I can't use C++11 and I can't have default parameters becouse later I have to make f.e. third<double> with other default params :C and can't change second<double> to second<double>::type

Comment: You're problem feels over-constrained to me. I would want to reject the requirement that specific classes exist and insist on being allowed to write the code in a way that is readable, simple and in the style of the version of c++ I have to use.